sample rate in A7672S GSM module
How can I set the sample rate in A7672S LTE module ?
I'm currently working with the A7672S GSM module and I need to adjust the sample rate for my project. However, I'm struggling to find clear documentation or resources on how to do this. Could someone please provide guidance on how to set the sample rate for the A7672S LTE module?
Additionally, I would appreciate any insights or experiences others have had with adjusting the sample rate on this specific module. Thank you in advance for your help!

Don't mistag your questions. Few of these tags have any relevance to your question. Can you clarify what you are referring to?  In the context of a Simcom A7672S I cannot see what you mean by sample rate.  What is it "sampling"? Did you mean data rate?

means ADC mic sample rate how to control

Sorry, I did not spot that it has a mic input.  Thought it was a data modem only.  I think though that for telephony, the sample rate is perhaps defined by standard for speech bandwidth requirements, and therefore fixed.  If you need higher fidelity you may need to use a separate audio sampling and transfer as data.  There was a reference to _ A76XX Series_AUDIO_Application_Note_ in the manual, but it does not seem to be freely available.  Perhaps if you have a relationship with SIMCom or a distributor you can obtain it.

... Took a look, and while GSM supports different data rates through different lossy compression CODECS, the sample rate is fixed at 4ksps. See https://www.quora.com/Why-are-cell-phone-calls-still-limited-by-the-4K-audio-sample-rate-established-in-the-1800s
